# Passing data between views in ONE ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, viewcontroller, subview

All of the searches I've done focus on passing data between view controllers.  That's not really what I'm trying to do. I have a ViewController that has multiple Views in it.  The ViewController has a slider which works fine:

```
var throttleSetting = Float()
@IBAction func changeThrottleSetting(sender: UISlider)
{
    throttleSetting = sender.value   
}
```

Then, in one of the Views contained in that same ViewController, I have a basic line that (for now) sets an initial value which is used later in the DrawRect portion of the code:

```
var RPMPointerAngle: CGFloat {
    var angle: CGFloat = 2.0
    return angle
}
```

What I want to do is have the slider's value from the ViewController be passed to the View contained in the ViewController to allow the drawRect to be dynamic.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: By Views, do you mean the Views of other ViewControllers being controlled by one ContainerViewController?

Comment: No, and I think my problem might be that I'm not really using the MVC method as it is meant to be used (I'm still learning).  Right now my app has only one ViewController.  In that ViewController, I have multiple Views (i.e. the generic View you can drag from the Object Library.  One of those Views is specifically being used to draw a bunch of BezierPaths using variables that I'd eventually like to come from other views on the screen (for now the variables are just static values so I can get the BezierPaths to look right).  I want the slider to be able to affect the value in a different View.

Comment: I'm not very sure what you've done (since the code you've provided is limited) But I think to change the slider, you can use a delegate. If you don't know what a delegate is, I can explain a bit for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, when I created this answer I was having ViewControllers in mind. A much easier way would be to create a method in SomeView and talk directly to it.

Example:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var view1: SomeView!
    var view2: SomeView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create the views here
        view1 = SomeView()
        view2 = SomeView()

        view.addSubview(view1)
        view.addSubview(view2)
    }

    @IBAction func someAction(sender: UIButton) {
        view1.changeString("blabla")
    }
}

class SomeView: UIView {

    var someString: String?

    func changeString(someText: String) {
        someString = someText
    }
}
```

Delegate:

First you create a protocol:

```
protocol NameOfDelegate: class {     // ": class" isn't mandatory, but it is when you want to set the delegate property to weak
    func someFunction()              // this function has to be implemented in your MainViewController so it can access the properties and other methods in there
}
```

In your Views you have to add:

```
class SomeView: UIView, NameOfDelegate {

    // your code

    func someFunction() {

        // change your slider settings
    }
}
```

And the last step, you'll have to add a property of the delegate, so you can "talk" to it. Personally I imagine this property to be a gate of some sort, between the two classes so they can talk to each other.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: NameOfDelegate?

    @IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
        if delegate != nil {
            let someString = delegate.someFunction()
        }
    }
}
```

I used a button here just to show how you could use the delegate. Just replace it with your slider to change the properties of your Views

EDIT: One thing I forgot to mention is, you'll somehow need to assign SomeView as the delegate. But like I said, I don't know how you're creating the views etc so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: So, when I input all that code, everything seems to work except on the UIView, I get an error that says "Type SomeView" does not conform to "NameOfDelegate".  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: That means you didn't implement the required function in `SomeView`. In this case that means, you'll have the exact same method as the one you've created in the delegate protocol: `func someFunction() -> String`. I noticed example is returning a string, which I think is not needed for you. Just in case, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Your edit answered 90% of the problem.  Here is what I have in my ViewController now:
`@IBOutlet weak var compactEngineView: BasicEngineGuagesUIView!`
`@IBAction func changeThrottleSetting(sender: UISlider)
{
    compactEngineView.RPMPointerAngleInt = Int(sender.value)
    println("\(compactEngineView.RPMPointerAngleInt)")    
 }`
Then in the View, I have this:
`var RPMPointerAngleInt = Int()`
The code runs just fine, but the DrawRect doesn't seem to update when the var in the View is updated by the slider.  Is there a trick to have the DrawRect continuously updating?

Comment: 100% Solved!  Between you and @Foebe, I got it to work!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

In the MVC model views can't communicate directly with each other.
There is always a view controller who manages the views. The views are just like the controllers minions.
All communication goes via a view controller.

If you want to react to some view changing, you can setup an `IBAction`. In the method you can then change your other view to which you might have an `IBOutlet`.

So in your example you might have an `IBAction` for the slider changing it's value (as in your original question) from which you could set some public properties on the view you would like to change. If necessary you could also call `setNeedsDisplay()` on the target view to make it redraw itself.