# How to pass a value from one UIView subclass to another UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController with a common UIView, `commonCenterView`,I added added a subview `NewsListView` to it, this is a table view, so when clicked on a cell, I'm adding another `UIView` - `NewsDetailsView` as a subview of `commonCenterView`.

Now, the problem is that, I need to pass a value from `NewsListView` to `NewsDetailsView` while initialising it, since the ViewOne and ViewTwo are from xib, I couldn't pass a value and get from  awakeFromNib() method, since it won't be initialised by then.Please help me solve this issue.

The code that I'd tried so far,

*In ViewOne(NewsListView)*

```
let newsView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NewsListView", owner: self, options: nil)
        newsListView = newsView?.first as! NewsListView
        newsListView.passigValue = 10
        newsListView.frame = CGRect(x:commonCenterView.frame.origin.x, y:0, width:commonCenterView.frame.size.width, height:commonCenterView.frame.size.height)
        commonCenterView.addSubview(newsListView)
        newsListView.delegate = self
```

*In ViewTwo(NewsDetailsView)*

import UIKit

```
class NewsDetailsView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var passingValue = Int()
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    print(passingValue)              //I understand that the value won’t be passed, since the view isn’t added yet
   }
}
```

Comment: Use custom Delegate to pass the value

Comment: Adding on to what @Bapu said, please check the answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934078/passing-data-between-views-in-one-viewcontroller-in-swift